# Use URL parameter as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to run an `onLoad` event to get data from my db. I need to use a url parameter as a the prop to do this with but can't figure out how to access it.

I am using `react-router v6`, although in my `package.json` it is called `react-router-dom`.

Here is my setup

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/newrecipe" element={<RecipeForm />} />
      <Route path="/recipe/:name" element={<RecipeDBTest />} /> //relevant line
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Then in `RecipeDBTest.jsx` I need to grab the final parameter from my url string that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/recipe/toast
```

So I would grab `toast` from URL string and pass to server with a fetch request on the `RecipeDBTest.jsx` page.

Just hoping for some advice/guidance here.

Comment: Did you read [the basic tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#reading-url-params)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useParams` hook of react-router.

```
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function Child() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { name } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Name: {name}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let name = this.props.match.params.name
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This answer is also completely incorrect. OP is using `react-router-dom@6` where there are no longer any route props. In other words, `this.props.match` is undefined.